# Additional backslash during XML to json conversion in XQuery Marklogic

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I'm working with XML to JSON conversion in XQuery for the content with special characters.

XML :
`<text>$$\parent* \$$</text>`

Using `json:transform-to-json()`  with **custom** config, getting the below result

Actual result: `{ "text": "$$\\parent* \\$$" }`

Expected result :
`{"text": "$$\parent* \$$"}`

I tried multiple ways like using `xdmp:quote()` and `xdmp:to-json()` methods but not giving the expected result.

Is there a way to restrict the addition of extra backslash during conversion in XQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{"text": "$$\parent* \$$"}` is not valid JSON.

In JSON the `\` needs to be escaped as `\\`.

You can verify that what is currently being produced is valid, and what you are expecting to be validated is invalid by validating them on https://jsonlint.com

Don't confuse what you see in the JSON value with the data that it represents. The value `$$\parent* \$$` in JSON is `$$\\parent* \\$$`, but when you parse/read and ask for the value of `text` using APIs, it will return `$$\parent* \$$`.

Comment: Our API is reading the response in JSON format.So this additional slash is expected to be retained there right?

Comment: Please check my query in previous comment and let me know